# Redefine active profiles after spring-boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I am using spring-boot 2, JUnit 5 and gradle.
I have the following test structure:

```
@Tag("integration")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class IntegrationTest {

    static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRESQL = ...
    static final LocalStackContainer LOCALSTACK = ...

    static {
        POSTGRESQL.start();
        LOCALSTACK.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add( ... );
    }
```

The given concrete class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("other-profile")
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
class Example extends IntegrationTest {
    
    @Test
    void exampleTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The tests are running completely fine and are doing what they are supposed to do, however when the test-suite is executed, all tests invoked after this class, which enables the profile `other-profile` will still have the profile enabled. My expectation was that this would happen only for the TestContext used in this class.
Is there any way to activate the profile only for this class and/or prevent that it's still active for the following tests?
Thank you!

Comment: I notice you have some `static` fields in your class. Are you sure that the problem comes from the profile, and not from reusing old instances?

Comment: @Jorn that could potentially be the cause, but best would be if I still could reuse them to avoid having to setup everything again, increasing the time it takes to run the test-suite.

Comment: I'm sure Spring has some way to tell you which profiles are active. It should be easy enough to check using that method in every test(class).

Comment: true, it's easy to check it, however there's a profile specific behaviour (enabled by other-profile) that will still be enabled for the other tests, when ideally it should not, and I guess it's not enough to just check the active profiles after the TestContext got created.